# Android: is it forbidden to access deviceId?

Tags: android, google-play

This code reads Android `device id`:

```
String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(App.getAppContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Is it forbidden to use this code inside apps published to Play Store?
I heard publishers are required to use `advertisingId` instead.

(In code I use `device id` as a constant in mathematics computations, without an attempt to gather personal data).

Answer (score 1):

No it's not forbidden. I have a published app on the play store that uses this. From the docs:

> Secure system settings, containing system preferences that
>   applications can read but are not allowed to write.

Notice the part about being allowed to read these settings, which is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) that states it is forbidden - using it in Play Store apps is perfectly fine.